# Debugging executed CodeDom?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, codedom

I am using codedom to execute some code. Is it possible to stop somehow the execution? here is how i run the code:

```
Dim SourceCode as String="... some VB code"
Dim MyProvider As New VBCodeProvider
Dim cp As New CompilerParameters
Dim cr As CompilerResults = MyProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, SourceCode)
Dim methInfo As MethodInfo = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Class1").GetMethod("Main")
methInfo.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

my idea is to put this in a threadworker and if I need to stop it, i stop the thread... but is there a better solution maybe? Thanks :)

Comment: Stopping code is completely different from debugging code.  What's the real question?

Comment: I want to be able to stop the code.

Comment: There is something that is not clear to me. Do you want to stop the assembly execution for debugging purposes and inspect the code at an arbitrary location?